# How can I get rid of the tiny fish-bone stuck in my throat upon eating fish?

Tags: food, comfort

My dinner is a fried [Milkfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milkfish). While I am eating a portion of this fish I feel a tiny bone is stuck near my throat.

What are some effective ways of removing this?

Comment: Note that your bone may have dislodged but you still feel it due to the small damage done to your throat.  Don't mess with it for about an hour and see if it improves.

Comment: Yeah you are right I also notice that.

Comment: never eat fish again

Answer (score 16):

A very easy method I've found is to eat marshmallows. You can use several mini ones or one or two big ones. Chew the marshmallows in your mouth, so that it becomes a sticky glob. Then swallow the glob. It should be sticky enough to grab the fishbone and drag it down your throat.

A variation of this is to use bread and peanut butter. Put peanut butter on a piece of bread, let it be moistened by the saliva, then swallow.

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is to eat a banana, it will help slip down the bone stuck in the throat.

I'm referring to [this article from ER Centers of America, Inc.](http://www.ercenters.com/blog/fishbone-first-aid.html)

Answer (score 8):

In the UK, we use dry bread, chewing it a bit to moisten slightly with saliva, and then swallowing the largest lump possible - this seems to scrape the throat and clear the problem. But sometimes, a trip to the A & E is necessary to have it taken out...

Answer (score 1):

Eat lots of bread at once- it helps if you chew as little as possible- then the bread keeps together and helps "clean" the throat by dislodging any obstructions.

for more see :
http://www.dw.de/how-to-dislodge-a-fish-bone-stuck-in-your-throat/a-18145579

Answer (score 0):

There a lot of methods to use. One of the best methods that I used for my mom. The best method is to swallow the bread with  warm water.

Don't chew the bread, just swallow the bread with warm water.

[For more methods](http://www.enkivillage.com/how-to-get-a-fishbone-out-of-your-throat.html).

Answer (score 0):

I just been through the 'horrowing' experience. Anxiety, Nervous and Panicking are the usual enemies when we caught under the situation. I tried everything according to the old teachings and methods but to no avail. Allow me to share some of my technique just in case you are running out of time but still feeling reluctant to consult doc.

First of all try settle down for a day if you have failed to withdraw the bone. Secondly you need to know the sensation of the bone hanging in your throat or beneath your tonsil or underneath the tongue. Well it can be everywhere. Get some rough estimation. Trust me, no one knows better where the bone stuck rather than our ownselves. Even doc sometimes can't locate the bone and forced to use anesthetic. Once you have settled down and had a great feeling that's the right spot, you need to find a plastic spoon and wooden chopstick to locate the bone real carefully. Use the plastic spoon holder to press on your tongue in order for you to search through your throat. You should able to control how deep reaching the end of the tongue as it's quite irritating and the feeling of 'puking'. If you let others or even a general doctor, they might probably mess up the process, which of course I did and not even a doctor who able to make it. So you need to take charge. Look at the mirror and use your mobile phone Torchlight to ease your operations.

Back to the tools, well now you know the plastic spoon function, use the chopstick to slowly open up your tonsils which located within the surrounding of your tongue. It's a very useful tool but you must do it real carefully not to hurt yourself.

Lastly, please remember this and it's quite important. The spot or stucking sensation in your throat may not be the exact spot. Throat created different and unique feeling and makes you believe that the bone was hanging there which it may be the opposite side. Remember this always, when you can't locate the bone where you have a strong feeling it's there. You need to try the opposite side, up down, left right. Open up your 4 tonsils or throat via chopstick. A few flicks, you may successfully pick out the bone.

I am just sharing and if you think your case is more severe,  you have no choice but to check with ENT specialist. Dentist can't do much either. And if you decided to check with ordinary surgeons, I would suggest that you try on the method. I wish you all the best.

Pls do not do this without the consent and supervision by the adults. And don't try this at home especially if you are not ready or equip with skills. Consult your doctors for proper medication.

Comment: Thankyou for answering, its just a tiny bone that makes me feel really annoyed upon swallowing saliva.

Answer (score 0):

There are some at-home remedies you can try in order to alleviate the throat irritation and pain brought about by a fish bone that gets stuck. You should try these remedies as soon as the bone gets stuck, and if none of these treatments work, go see a doctor.
1. Cough

The very first thing you can try is coughing. In some cases, heavy coughing can help dislodge the stuck bone.
2. Drink Salty Water

If coughing does not work, you should take a glass of lukewarm water, add a pinch of salt to it, and then drink the mixture. If the fish bone is small enough, it will be dislodged by the salt water and be taken down the alimentary canal to your stomach.
3. Ingest Marshmallows

You can also try the ingestion of marshmallows as a remedy. Fill your mouth with just enough marshmallows to make chewing possible. Only chew on these marshmallows a little bit and then swallow. The lump of marshmallows will be sticky, and once swallowed, it might be enough to take the bone down to the stomach. Make sure you drink water after this. Similarly, you can rely on a piece of bread and peanut butter to provide stickiness that is similar to that provided by marshmallows. Alternatively, if there is sticky rice available to you, take a spoonful of it and swallow it without chewing. Be careful not to ingest too much of it, or you might risk choking.
4. Drink Olive Oil

Another thing you can try is to soften the fish bone stuck in throat. In a glass of water, boil a handful of olives. Drink the liquid while it is warm, so that the bone can be softened and possibly taken down the esophagus. You can also try drinking warm olive oil to provide lubrication.
5. Try Banana

Take some banana and keep it in your mouth for a few minutes until it moistens. Make sure you do not chew it! Once it is moist enough, slowly swallow it. The stickiness of the banana may attract the fish bone and if it does, the bone will easily be taken down to the stomach.
6. Drink Vinegar

Some people suggest drinking diluted vinegar to soften and even dissolve the bone. The success of this method has yet to be reported widely, but this is still worth trying.
7. Medical Treatment

Medical treatment to remove fish bone stuck in throat works through a series of steps.

Firstly, to determine the exact location of the fish bone stuck in your throat, the medical care provider may carry out an X-ray that involves ingesting a barium-based liquid. Other methods include a laryngoscopy to have a look at the back of your throat, a CT scan in extreme cases, and an endoscopy to determine the level of damage that the fish bone has caused to your digestive tract.
  When the location is determined, using forceps will usually be the first method to remove the fish bone. Endoscopy may also be used to remove the bone in cases where forceps fail to retrieve the bone. In very rare cases, surgery may be required.
  Once the object has been taken out, some medications may be prescribed, depending on the severity of the lodging of the fish bone in your throat.

When to See a Doctor

If the home remedies fail and your condition is accompanied by the following symptoms, you should seek immediate help from a doctor:

Pain when swallowing or even a sore throat vomiting blood
    Difficulty breathing or breathing that is accompanied by coughs, choking or gagging
    Pain in chest and abdomen
    Fever

Even when the home remedies do help you remove the fish bone stuck in throat, you'd better pay close attention to the above symptoms and see your doctor if you have similar discomfort.

Answer (score 0):

Well! It all depends on the nature at which the bone is stuck to your throat, and its distance from your mouth. For me, after taking a full orange, I tried reaching it carefully with my index finger, as it was close to my salivary gland, and it came off without stress. Well I think you should also try to see if you can reach it with your finger, I wouldn't advice the use of anything other than the finger. Using your Finger helps you to be more careful, than when you use other objects. If it doesn't work for you, I guess you gonna have to try other given methods then.